# "The system cannot find the file specified" when animating with ffmpeg in matplotlib

Tags: python, windows, matplotlib, ffmpeg

I am trying to generate a movie from a stack of numpy arrays using a function I have used on a different computer (a mac) on my home computer (Windows 10). Here is the function that I am using:

```
def make_animation(frames,name): 

    plt.rcParams['animation.ffmpeg_path'] = u'C:\ffmpeg-20190320-0739d5c-win64-static\bin\ffmpeg.exe' 
    n_images=frames.shape[2] 
    assert (n_images>1)   
    figsize=(10,10)
    fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=figsize)
    fig.tight_layout()
    fig.subplots_adjust(left=0, bottom=0, right=1, top=1, wspace=None, hspace=None)
    #lineR, = ax.plot(xaxis_data[0],R_data[0],'c-',label="resources")
    img = ax.imshow(frames[:,:,0], animated = True)   


    def updatefig(img_num): 

        #lineR.set_data(xaxis_data[img_num],R_data[img_num],'r-')

        img.set_data(frames[:,:,img_num])

        return [img]


    ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, updatefig, np.arange(1, n_images), interval=50, blit=True)
    mywriter = animation.FFMpegWriter(fps = 20)
    #ani.save('mymovie.mp4',writer=mywriter)

    ani.save(f"D:\{name}.mp4",writer=mywriter)

    plt.close(fig)
```

Here is the error that I am getting:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-48-8861d4da3f36>", line 1, in <module>
    make_animation(stack,'full_test')

  File "<ipython-input-47-0e3683911f60>", line 27, in make_animation
    ani.save(f"D:\{name}.mp4",writer=mywriter)

  File "C:\Users\~snip~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\animation.py", line 1136, in save
    with writer.saving(self._fig, filename, dpi):

  File "C:\Users\~snip~\Anaconda3\lib\contextlib.py", line 112, in __enter__
    return next(self.gen)

  File "C:\Users\~snip~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\animation.py", line 228, in saving
    self.setup(fig, outfile, dpi, *args, **kwargs)

  File "C:\Users\~snip~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\animation.py", line 352, in setup
    self._run()

  File "C:\Users\~snip~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\animation.py", line 363, in _run
    creationflags=subprocess_creation_flags)

  File "C:\Users\~snip~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder_kernels\customize\spydercustomize.py", line 143, in __init__
    super(SubprocessPopen, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

  File "C:\Users\~snip~\Anaconda3\lib\subprocess.py", line 775, in __init__
    restore_signals, start_new_session)

  File "C:\Users\~snip~\Anaconda3\lib\subprocess.py", line 1178, in _execute_child
    startupinfo)

FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified
```

I know this code basically works since I have used it before on another computer. My guess is that something about ffmpeg is messed up or something about the output path is wrong. I'm not sure what could be wrong with the ffmpeg since I definitely have it installed (via conda) and the path is pretty straightforward. On the other hand I'm not sure what could be wrong with the output path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe in this case is because the file path is wrong.

> using a function I have used on a different computer (a mac)

So I believe the previous file path is represented using `/`. And now you change it to `\` since Windows use a different separator. Seems alright?

No.

Because in python and most programming languages, `\` is a reserved flag indicator for string. For example`\n` means new line. Therefore, you should use `\\` instead, for example `"D:\\{name}.mp4"` instead of `""D:\{name}.mp4`.

Another thing you can use is `os.path.join`, and example can be found at

```
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-os-path-join-method/
```

But in this case, you will want your files in the same path, at least same relative path.